# React-native upload jpg file to s3

Tags: react-native

I've been trying to upload a file to S3 - the requirement is that whether it is from Android or iOS that the file is readable by the web (i.e. is an ordinary jpeg file).

I've tried without success to use react-native-fetch-blob and `RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(image.path, 'base64').then(data => //upload here );`
but all I am able to upload is a baset64 representation of the file.

This is not acceptable as cannot be read natively by a web interface.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This function work for me, hope this help

```
async function uploadFile(signed_url, uri, fileName, fileType, callback) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('PUT', signed_url);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', fileType);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                console.log(log_sign, "upload success");
                callback(xhr.status)
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.send({uri: uri, type: fileType, name: fileName})
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Steps using aws3 lib.

1. Install aws3 react-native library using command `npm install --save react-native-aws3`
2. Use the following code to as template to upload the jpg.

   ```
   import { RNS3 } from 'react-native-aws3';

   // No need to convert to Base 64. You can directly upload the image.
   const imageFile = {
     uri: `file://${image.path}`,
    name: "image.png",
    type: "image/png"
   }

   // Replace your s3 configuration here. Also move this to separate file for better use.
   const options = {
     keyPrefix: "uploads/",
     bucket: "your-bucket",
     region: "us-east-1",
     accessKey: "your-access-key",
     secretKey: "your-secret-key",
     successActionStatus: 201
   }

   RNS3.put(imageFile, options).then(response => {
     if (response.status !== 201) throw new Error("Failed to upload image to S3");

     console.log(response.body);
     /**
     * {
     *   postResponse: {
     *     bucket: "your-bucket",
     *     etag : "9f620878e06d28774406017480a59fd4",
     *     key: "uploads/image.png",
     *     location: "https://your-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads%2Fimage.png"
     *   }
     * }
     */
   });
   ```

Also there is a native library for react native call react-native-s3. If you want check it out too.